# Is it possible to use the deduction theorem as a "meta-axiom" of sorts to generate a new theory?

Tags: logic

It's possible to define a logic without inference rules (or where every inference rule has premises) and hence no unconditional tautologies.

The deduction theorem is a *meta-theoretical* property of a system, but I think it is also possible to use it or something similar to it to generate a new system by mapping every [proof tree]/[conditional tautology] to an unconditional tautology. I'm non-standardly calling this process the **deductive closure**. In the example of the simply typed lambda calculus, taking just the introduction and elimination rules for the connectives and then producing a new system seems to work as a means of generating the simply-typed lambda calculus.

*Is this process legitimate? Does it have a name?*

---

In the example below $Y^X$ is an orthographic abbreviation of $X \to Y$ used occasionally to conserve space. The connective $\to$ is right-associative.

The setting below is a fragment of the simply typed lambda calculus with no axioms. Equivalently, it is intuitionistic logic with a notation for proof objects that are redundantly expressed throughout the proof tree. Let's call this system $T_1$.

$$ \frac{x:A \;\;\;\; y:B}{(x,y):A\land B} \;\;\;\; \frac{x:A}{\text{inl}(x):A\lor B} \;\;\;\; \frac{y : B}{\text{inr}(y):A \lor B} \;\;\;\; \frac{v:B}{\lambda(x,v):A \to B}  $$

$$ \frac{v:A \land B}{\pi_1(v):A} \;\;\;\; \frac{v : A \land B}{\pi_2(v):B} \;\;\;\; \frac{f:A\to B\;\;\;\; x:A}{f[x]:B} \;\;\;\; \frac{v : C^{A {\lor} B} \;\; f:C^A \;\; g:C^B}{\text{case}(v,f,g): C} $$

We have some inherent rules for proof trees such as the following one which discards an unneeded premise.

$$ \frac{x:A \;\;\;\; y:B}{x:A} $$

The deduction theorem is stated below.

$$ \text{If $\Delta \cup {A} \vdash B$ ,  then $\Delta \vdash A \to B$} $$

If $\Delta$ is a finite sequence $\Delta_1, \cdots, \Delta_n$, then the following is true by repeated application of the deduction theorem.

$$ \text{If $\Delta_1, \cdots, \Delta_n \vdash W$ , then $ \vdash \Delta_1 \to \Delta_2 \to \cdots \to \Delta_n \to W$  } $$

This meta-theorem gives us an interesting sort of closure property, we can use it to produce the **deductive closure** of $T_1$, which I'll call $T_2$. Instead of merely assessing whether the deduction theorem holds, we *force it to hold* in the new system by insisting on an axiom for every proof tree.

As an example, $A \to A$ is an unconditional tautology of $T_2$ but not $T_1$.

To show it, we note that $\frac{A}{A}$ is a valid proof tree in $T_1$ and then invoke our closure property to prove $\frac{ }{A \to A}$.

Comment: What is the difference with [Natural Deduction](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/) ? Basically DT is "built in" into $\to$-intro rule (your fourth rule).

Comment: Based on the article, I think what I'm proposing is a different way of organizing the bookkeeping of active hypotheses. I think in the case of intuitionistic logic, the $\to$-introduction rule is the only one that can discharge hypotheses. Rephrasing my question, is it legitimate to *transform proof trees into axioms for later use* as an alternative to the other mechanisms of keeping track of active assumptions?